# Created User in Linux (Ubuntu) Without Creating a Home Directory - Causing Problems

Tags: linux, user-accounts, home-folder

This may be a rookie mistake, but I created a user (new user) in Linux on a Ubuntu system and didn't actually create the home directory for this user.  Now, when I log in, it says there are problems...  If I delete the path `home/<new user>` and try to log in the system tells me I can use root as home directory but I will likely experience problems, and then it won't let me log in.

What is the best way to create this directory with the appropriate permissions?  Should I just create another user and delete this one?  I need some help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the directory, chown it to <new user>:<new group>, chmod it 0700, and copy *all* the contents, including hidden files, of /etc/skel to the new home directory.

Comment: ...and then make sure the path to that directory is set properly as the user's home in */etc/passwd* ... also, it's probably better to copy the contents of */etc/skel* to the new home directory before *chown* -ing and *chmod* -ing it.

Comment: Right, yes. Copy, then change permissions. Files should be 0600, directories should be 0700.